# Passing discriminated unions to InlineData attributes

Tags: unit-testing, f#, xunit, discriminated-union

I am trying to unit test a parser that parses a string and returns the corresponding abstract syntax tree (represented as a discriminated union). I figured it would be pretty compact to use Xunit.Extensions' attribute `InlineData` to stack all test cases on one another:

```
[<Theory>]
[<InlineData("1 +1 ", Binary(Literal(Number(1.0)), Add, Literal(Number(1.0))))>]
...
let ``parsed string matches the expected result`` () =
```

However, compiler complains that the second argument is not a literal (compile time constant if I understand it correctly).

Is there a workaround for this? If not, what would be the most sensible way to structure parser result tests while keeping every case as a separate unit test?

Comment: Don't use attributes. If you want to keep using Xunit, see http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/03/14/exude/ , otherwise see https://github.com/mausch/Fuchu

Comment: @MauricioScheffer I've actually seen that blog post some time ago, thanks for reminding me about it. However, R#'s test runner does not pick up the Exude style tests in F# :/. It works in C#, but the test results behave strangely when one of the "nested" tests fails.

Comment: Actually, scratch that. It does work in F#, I just defined the test as a value, not as a function. It's a little annoying that R#'s test runner identifies the sequence of test cases as one unit test. Xunit console runner does not have this problem. Feel free to post your suggestion as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: The usual test runners are chock-full of magic and therefore will break all the time. Long-term it's just best to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use xUnit's `MemberData` attribute.  A disadvantage with this approach is that this parameterized test appears in Visual Studio's Test Explorer as one test instead of two separate tests because collections lack xUnit's `IXunitSerializable` interface and xUnit hasn't added build-in serialization support for that type either.  See [xunit/xunit/issues/429](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/429) for more information.

Here is a minimal working example.

```
module TestModule

  open Xunit

  type DU = A | B | C

  type TestType () =
    static member TestProperty
      with get() : obj[] list =
        [
          [| A; "a" |]
          [| B; "b" |]
        ]

    [<Theory>]
    [<MemberData("TestProperty")>]            
    member __.TestMethod (a:DU) (b:string) =
      Assert.Equal(A, a)
```

See also this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35026735/in-f-how-do-you-pass-a-collection-to-xunits-inlinedata-attribute) in which I give a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35026735/in-f-how-do-you-pass-a-collection-to-xunits-inlinedata-attribute/57282819#57282819).