# In F# how do you pass a collection to xUnit's InlineData attribute

Tags: .net, f#, tdd, xunit

I would like to be about to use a list, array, and/or seq as a parameter to xUnit's InlineData.

In C# I can do this:

```
using Xunit; //2.1.0

namespace CsTests
{
    public class Tests
    {
        [Theory]
        [InlineData(new[] {1, 2})]
        public void GivenCollectionItMustPassItToTest(int[] coll)
        {
            Assert.Equal(coll, coll);
        }
    }
}
```

In F# I have this:

```
namespace XunitTests

module Tests =
  open Xunit //2.1.0

  [<Theory>]
  [<InlineData(8)>]
  [<InlineData(42)>]
  let ``given a value it must give it to the test`` (value : int) =
    Assert.Equal(value, value)

  [<Theory>]
  [<InlineData([1; 2])>]
  let ``given a list it should be able to pass it to the test``
  (coll : int list) =
    Assert.Equal<int list>(coll, coll)

  [<Theory>]
  [<InlineData([|3; 4|])>]
  let ``given an array it should be able to pass it to the test``
  (coll : int array) =
    Assert.Equal<int array>(coll, coll)
```

The F# code give the following build errors:

> Library1.fs (13, 16): This is not a valid constant expression or custom attribute value
>
> Library1.fs (18, 16): This is not a valid constant expression or custom attribute value

Referring to the 2nd and 3rd test theories.

Is it possible to use xUnit to pass in collections to the InlineData attribute?

Comment: Thanks James, if that is the case how do people normally hand needing a collection for test data in F#?

Comment: I'd suggested this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349152/cannot-create-list-literal-in-f.  However that question is specifically how to create a literal list in F# (and the answer is: you can't).  This question is "How can I use xUnit and pass in a list of test data".  Looks like @bytebuster has a workable answer.

Comment: You can't use lists, but you ought to be able to use arrays like in C#, but I've never been able to make it compile. Fortunately, this becomes irrelevant once you discover [FsCheck.Xunit](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/RunningTests.html).

Comment: @MarkSeemann thanks. I was hoping there was a solution for example based testing, but maybe I need to use property based testing more.

Comment: This question shows other ways of achieving the same goal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093843/pass-complex-parameters-to-theory

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`InlineDataAttribute` leans on the C# `params` mechanism. This is what enables the default syntax of InlineData in C# :-

```
[InlineData(1,2)]
```

Your version with array construction:-

```
[InlineData( new object[] {1,2})]
```

is simply what the compiler translates the above into. The minute you go further, you'll run into the same restrictions on what the CLI will actually enable - the bottom line is that at the IL level, using attribute constructors implies that everything needs to be boiled down to constants at compile time. The F# equivalent of the above syntax is simply: `[<InlineData(1,2)>]`, so the direct answer to your question is:

```
module UsingInlineData =
    [<Theory>]
    [<InlineData(1, 2)>]  
    [<InlineData(1, 1)>]  
    let v4 (a : int, b : int) : unit = Assert.NotEqual(a, b)
```

---

I was unable to avoid riffing on @bytebuster's example though :) If we define a helper:-

```
type ClassDataBase(generator : obj [] seq) = 
    interface seq<obj []> with
        member this.GetEnumerator() = generator.GetEnumerator()
        member this.GetEnumerator() = 
            generator.GetEnumerator() :> System.Collections.IEnumerator
```

Then (if we are willing to forgo laziness), we can abuse `list` to avoid having to use `seq` / `yield` to win the code golf:-

```
type MyArrays1() = 
    inherit ClassDataBase([ [| 3; 4 |]; [| 32; 42 |] ])

[<Theory>]
[<ClassData(typeof<MyArrays1>)>]
let v1 (a : int, b : int) : unit = Assert.NotEqual(a, b)
```

But the raw syntax of `seq` can be made sufficiently clean, so no real need to use it as above, instead we do:

```
let values : obj[] seq = 
    seq { 
        yield [| 3; 4 |] 
        yield [| 32; 42 |] // in recent versions of F#, `yield` is optional in seq too
    }

type ValuesAsClassData() = 
    inherit ClassDataBase(values)

[<Theory; ClassData(typeof<ValuesAsClassData>)>]
let v2 (a : int, b : int) : unit = Assert.NotEqual(a, b)
```

---

However, most idiomatic with xUnit v2 for me is to use straight `MemberData`  (which is like xUnit v1's `PropertyData` but generalized to also work on fields) :-

```
[<Theory; MemberData("values")>]
let v3 (a : int, b : int) : unit = Assert.NotEqual(a, b)
```

The key thing to get right is to put the `: seq<obj>` (or `: obj[] seq`) on the declaration of the sequence or xUnit will throw at you.

---

Later versions of xUnit 2 include a typed TheoryData, which lets you write:

```
type Values() as this =
    inherit TheoryData<int,int>()
    do  this.Add(3, 4)
        this.Add(32, 42)

[<Theory; ClassData(typeof<Values>)>]
let v2 (a : int, b : int) : unit = Assert.NotEqual(a, b)
```

That also type-checks each argument.

[Current xUnit v2 releases let you replace the `Add` with constructor calls](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/2854), e.g.:

```
type Values() =
    inherit TheoryData<_, _>([
        3, 4
        32, 42 ])

[<Theory; ClassData(typeof<Values>)>]
let v2 (a : int, b : int) : unit = Assert.NotEqual(a, b)
```

Comment: Thanks this works, but NCrunch does not seem to like MemberData.  O-well, I'll most likely either use a Fact or FsCheck going forward.

Comment: Is it `Theory` or `MemberData` it doesnt like? If its the latter, then you should be able to make `PropertyData` work - just add `with get()` to the field? You're right about having ample substitutes - in general it's easy enough to make each leg of a Theory an individually addressable Fact and probably end up with more readable code.

Answer (score 10):

As described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349152/cannot-create-list-literal-in-f), you can only use literals with `InlineData`. Lists are not literals.

However, xUnit provides with `ClassData` which seems to do what you need.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093843/pass-complex-parameters-to-theory) discusses the same problem for C#.

In order to use `ClassData` with the tests, just make a data class implementing `seq<obj[]>`:

```
type MyArrays () =    
    let values : seq<obj[]> = seq {
       [|3; 4|]    // 1st test case
       [|32; 42|]  // 2nd test case, etc.
    }
    interface seq<obj[]> with
        member this.GetEnumerator () = values.GetEnumerator()
        member this.GetEnumerator () =
            values.GetEnumerator() :> System.Collections.IEnumerator

module Theories = 
    [<Theory>]
    [<ClassData(typeof<MyArrays1>)>]
    let ``given an array it should be able to pass it to the test`` (a : int, b : int) : unit = 
        Assert.NotEqual(a, b)
```

Albeit this requires some manual coding, you may re-use the data class, which appears to be useful in real-life projects, where we often run different tests against the same data.

Comment: I cannot get this solution to work as is, but I see where you are going and believe this the "correct" answer. Thank you I will make it as correct once I get it to work.

Comment: The seq { [|3; 4|] [|32; 43|] } is not a valid seq expression, I ended up using 
type MyArrays () =    
    let values =
        seq [
            [|3; 4|]    // 1st test case
            [|32; 42|]  // 2nd test case, etc.
        ]
        |> Seq.cast<obj>
    interface seq<obj[]> with
        member this.GetEnumerator<'T> () = values.GetEnumerator() :> System.Collections.Generics.IEnumerator<'T>
        member this.GetEnumerator () =
            values.GetEnumerator() :> System.Collections.IEnumerator

Comment: @MikeHarris You are correct in your suppositions, I've edited in two missing yield operators and a type mistake [And an answer expanding on all this below]

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the member data without class:

```
let memberDataProperty = seq {
    yield [| box "param1"; box param2; box expectedResult |]
}

[<Theory; MemberData(nameof memberDataProperty)>]
let ``Can use MemberData`` param1 param2 expectedResult = ...
```

Comment: nice - some tweaks 1) you can use `box` instead of `:> Object` 2) if using F# 4.7, you can use nameof to derive `"memberDataProperty"`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `FSharp.Reflection` namespace to good effect here. Consider some hypothetical function `isAnswer : (string -> int -> bool)` that you want to test with a few examples.

Here's one way:

```
open FSharp.Reflection
open Xunit

type TestData() =
  static member MyTestData =
    [ ("smallest prime?", 2, true)
      ("how many roads must a man walk down?", 41, false) 
    ] |> Seq.map FSharpValue.GetTupleFields

[<Theory; MemberData("MyTestData", MemberType=typeof<TestData>)>]
let myTest (q, a, expected) =
  Assert.Equals(isAnswer q a, expected)
```

The key thing is the `|> Seq.map FSharpValue.GetTupleFields` line.
It takes the list of tuples (you have to use tuples to allow different arguments types) and transforms it to the `IEnumerable<obj[]>` that XUnit expects.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to use xUnit's `MemberData` attribute.  A disadvantage with this approach is that this parameterized test appears in Visual Studio's Test Explorer as one test instead of two separate tests because collections lack xUnit's `IXunitSerializable` interface and xUnit hasn't added build-in serialization support for that type either.  See [xunit/xunit/issues/429](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/429) for more information.

Here is a minimal working example.

```
module TestModule

  open Xunit

  type TestType () =
    static member TestProperty
      with get() : obj[] list =
        [
          [| [0]; "a" |]
          [| [1;2]; "b" |]
        ]

    [<Theory>]
    [<MemberData("TestProperty")>]            
    member __.TestMethod (a:int list) (b:string) =
      Assert.Equal(1, a.Length)
```

See also this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726058/passing-discriminated-unions-to-inlinedata-attributes) in which I give a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726058/passing-discriminated-unions-to-inlinedata-attributes/57282762#57282762).

Answer (score 3):

Building further on @Assassin's brilliant answer -- now we have implicit yields you can put the test cases in an array and dispense with the `yield`s.  I would also be tempted to add a cheeky little private operator to handle the object conversions.  Thus:

```
open System
open Xunit

let inline private (~~) x = x :> Object

let degreesToRadiansCases =
    [|
        // Degrees; Radians
        [|   ~~0.0;            ~~0.0  |]
        [| ~~360.0; ~~(Math.PI * 2.0) |]
    |]

[<Theory>]
[<MemberData("degreesToRadiansCases")>]
let ``Convert from degrees to radians`` (degrees, radians) =
    let expected = radians
    let actual = Geodesy.Angle.toRadians degrees
    Assert.Equal(expected, actual)

let stringCases =
    [|
        [| ~~99; ~~"hello1" |] 
        [| ~~99; ~~"hello2" |] 
    |]

[<Theory>]
[<MemberData("stringCases")>]
let ``tests`` (i, s) =
    printfn "%i %s" i s
    Assert.Equal(s, "hello1")
```

Comment: You can drop the `~~` operator if you use `degreesToRadiansCases: Object [] []`, as shown in Tyson's answer.